# Using an Interface in Java

Tags: java, interface, tree

Well I have a fairly simple question I just can't seem to find my way around...

For a class, I have to implement an interface for a binary tree that has a method like:

```
public List<Node<E>> listAll();
```

we are required to have a class called MyNode.java, which is what I use to make my tree with. So to list all children I thought I would do this:

```
public List<Node<E>> listAll(){
    List<Node<E>> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyNode<E> thisNode = this.l;

    while(thisNode!= null){
        childList.add(thisNode);
        thisNode = thisNode.l;
    }

    return childList;
 }
```

and to do something like set a child

```
public void setChild(Node<E> child){
    E elem = child.getElement();
    MyNode<E> newNode = new MyNode(elem);
    this.l = newNode;
}
```

So my question is: am I going about this correctly? If I try to create a Node, I can't because my nodes are called MyNodes but when I try to create a list of MyNodes and return them it gives me an error because I am not following the interface.. When I try to make the method accept MyNode instead of Node it says I am not following the interface. A little more clarification below..

I currently am using the implements declaration to implement the Node.java interface.. When I am writing the method that is specified by my interface as:

```
public void setChild(Node<E> child);
```

then I am currently fleshing out the method like so:

```
public void setChild(Node<E> child) {
    E elem = child.getElement();
    MyNode<E> newNode = new MyNode<E>(elem);
    MyNode<E> transNode = this.l;
    if(transNode!=null){
        while(transNode.r!=null){
            transNode = transNode.r;
        }
        transNode = newNode;
    }
    else transNode = newNode;
}
```

you can see how I am getting the element from input child and creating a new MyNode out of it to put as the new child instead of just injecting Node into my tree.. Is this wrong? I can't seem to get another way to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are good for making code generic. If you wanted to have multiple implementations of a Node class that each would have the same methods then making an interface would be a good idea.

Alternatively, if you want to enforce an API for someone else to use, and interface is the right way to do that. You can make methods that accept any object that implements that interface.

If you're just creating one Node class for a simple binary tree implementation it might not make sense. Your binary tree might want to implement a Collection interface to make it available as a generic structure.

If you want to contractualize yourself to an API before beginning, an interface could further be a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't want to create an interface unless you want an abstraction where you actually will write different implementations of that abstraction. In your case, `class Node<T>` will suffice for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered good form to use an interface for the API.
Briefly, doing so:

- allowing the caller to provide whatever implementation they like
- makes testing easier, especially when using mocks
- chisels the least amount of the API in stone

See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)